# Can't destroy PouchDB

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, pouchdb

I'm having trouble deleting my PouchDB to reset my jQuery Mobile app.

(Equivalent jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYR8c/2/)

I have in `app.js`:

```
var db = new PouchDB('petrolog');

function resetDb(){
    db.destroy(function(err, info) { console.log('Error: ' + err); 
       console.log('Info: ' + info); }); //this is line 38, referenced in errors below
    showFillups(); //redraws the UI
}
```

and in `index.html`:

```
<head>
<script src="http://download.pouchdb.com/pouchdb-nightly.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="btnResetDb" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all">Erase all fillups</a>

<script> $('#btnResetDb').click(function(event){resetDb();}); </script>
</body>
```

When I click the button, I get the following from FireBug:

```
Error: null        app.js (line 38)
Info: undefined    app.js (line 38)
```

*these correspond to my `db.destroy()` instruction in `resetDb()`*

Any suggestions? I've already checked the API docs at http://pouchdb.com/api.html#delete_database but didn't find much help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `destroy()` method doesn't actually return anything for `info`.  The fact that `error` is null indicates that everything was successful.

This is actually a bug in the documentation of PouchDB, which we'll fix.

FWIW, though, your jsfiddle doesn't work for unrelated reasons: the fiddle environment doesn't seem to have access to any local databases, so in Firefox I see `Error: No valid adapter found`.

Comment: Just a quick question: it says that destroy is deprected, so should I just mark all entrys/documents deleted and then compact the thing?

Comment: `destroy()` is a separate operation from compaction, and it's `PouchDB.destroy()` that's deprecated, not `db.destroy()`. I'll update the docs to make that clearer.